# Change image and label on keypress in kivy

Tags: python, keypress, kivy, keyboard-events

I am learning using kivy right now on my Raspberry-Pi. I installed the most recent kivypie image and I do want to make a simle app, which changes an image content and some label on buttonpress and keypress.

The buttonpress works as expected, but the after pressing uo/down keys on the keyboard only the label text changes and no image is being displayed.

Also I can quit the App pressing the q button but not the escape button as I would like.

Here is my current code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.image = Image(source='test.png',
                       allow_stretch=True,
                       keep_ratio=True)
        root.add_widget(self.image)
        self.label = Label(text='Some long and very explanatory text. This is a representation of a custom image description'
                      ' coming with the image. This text can split over several lines and will fit in a box'
                      'defined by the text_size property.',
                      font_size=28,
                      text_size=(600, None),
                      color=(0, 1, 1, 1),
                      size_hint=(1, .2))
        root.add_widget(self.label)
        button = Button(text="Change",
                    size_hint=(1, .07))
        button.bind(on_press=self.callback)

        root.add_widget(button)

        return root

    def callback(self, value):
        self.image.source = 'test.jpg'
        self.label.text = 'No text'

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        #print('### ----------------------------------- ###')
        #print('The key', keycode, 'have been pressed')
        #print(' - text is %r' % text)
        #print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)

        if text == 'escape':
            App.get_running_app().stop()
            #keyboard.release()
        elif text == 'q':
            App.get_running_app().stop()
            #keyboard.release()
        elif text == 'up':
            self.image.source = 'test.jpg'
            self.label.text = 'No text'
            #keyboard.release()
        elif text == 'down':
            self.image.source = 'test.jpg'
            self.label.text = 'No text'
            #keyboard.release()
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: The code you posted does not execute.  You have an indentation problem in ```build(self)``` and you are referencing attributes that don't exist.

Comment: There was a wrong indentation at the end of the build() method caused by the stackoverflow editor. I already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you uncomment your print statements, you'll see the information you are looking for is in `keycode`, not `text`.  `text` will only match lettered keys, for special keys (escape, up, down, etc) it will not.  Try changing it such that:

```
def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    print('### ----------------------------------- ###')
    print('The key', keycode, 'have been pressed')
    print(' - text is %r' % text)
    print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)

    key = keycode[1]
    if key == 'escape':
        App.get_running_app().stop()
        #keyboard.release()
    elif key == 'q':
        App.get_running_app().stop()
        #keyboard.release()
    elif key == 'up':
        self.image.source = 'test2.png'
        self.label.text = 'No text'
        #keyboard.release()
    elif key == 'down':
        self.image.source = 'test2.png'
        self.label.text = 'No text'
        #keyboard.release()
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort but sadly your suggestion did not helt me. The esc key is still not recognized propperly - could it be caused by the fact, that I am running kivy on Raspberry Pi ? The print statements do not sho any valid output when esc is pressed, only those characters [^[^[^[^[^... And the picture is still not changing on key-press.

Comment: It might be a Pi thing, I tried it on Ubuntu on my desktop and it worked as you described.

Comment: And you are right ... sadly. I installed the newest version from the ubuntu PPA and the change of the image works as expected. The esc key is recognized as well. I will try to update the R-Pi system and see if this will bring something.

Comment: No change even after update to the newest 1.9.0 version of kivy so I opened a issue on github. Thank everyone for your kindly help !